# How to print table data using print statement in Karate API?

Tags: web-services, testing, automation, karate

I need to understand how the **Table** concept is working in Karate API. So I just tried with the following example. I have created a feature file like this.

```
Feature: RCI Webservices Testing

Background:
* url 'test-something-url'

Scenario: JavaAPI Handler
Given request read('test.xml') 
When method post
Then status 200

xmlstring xmlVar = response

* table xmlResponse
   | xmlData | filename        | statuscode     |
   | xmlVar  | 'Customers.xml' | responseStatus |    

* print 'Table Data :', <xmldata> (**tried without < > also** )
```

When I run this script through a java class i.e. JUnit Test, I'm not seeing anything in the print statement except **Table Data:**

Even I read the documentation, I'm not able to understand how does it work?

It will be helpful if you provide an example.

Thanks

Comment: Accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an example, here you go: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature) just cut and paste from this and experiment.